# Concatenate array with same number of rows but different columns

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
def preprocess(numerical , categorical):
    imputer = SimpleImputer()
    x_num = imputer.fit_transform(numerical)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    x_num = scaler.fit_transform(x_num)
    one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
    x_cat = one_hot.fit_transform(categorical)
    print('X_num Shape : ' , x_num.shape)
    print('X_cat Shape : ' , x_cat.shape)
    
    return np.concatenate((x_num,x_cat),axis = 1)
```

```
[Output] X_num Shape :  (889, 2)
         X_cat Shape :  (889, 22)
```

The Error it shows at the end is `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)`

I want the output to be of shape (889,24)

last sentence ( array at index 1 has 0 dimensions ) drives me to think that the problem is related to the weird numpy arrays of shape (n,) and (,n) but that shouldn't be a problem as dimensions are shown to not be that way but I think there's something I'm missing

I've also tried using a lot of different functions `np.hstack , np.vstack , np.column_stack` but they either dont give the desired output or show this error message `ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2 and the array at index 1 has size 1`

Comment: check for the arg `axis`,try with `axis = 0`

Comment: Tried it gives same error message `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
`

Comment: `np.concatenate((x,y),axis=1)` works fine for my dummy array,check your dtypes of the arrays

Comment: X_cat shape type is `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` . I think thats it will try and get back to you

Comment: Sparse matrices cannot be joined with `np.concatenate`.  Look at `np.array(X_cat).shape`.  There's your 1d array.

Comment: Your `one-hot` is producing a sparse matrix (check its default parameters).  Either change that sparse setting, make the result dense, or use `sparse.hstack`.   This is a tricky error (I've seen it a few times before), but ultimately it comes down to too casual reading of the documentation.

Comment: Thank you both for helping. adding the parameter `sparse = False` in OneHotEncoder Solved this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as hpaulj mentioned above the problem was that the type of `x_cat` after coming out of OneHotEncoder was `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`  instead of a numpy array which cannot be concatenated with other numpy array which results in it being cast into a numpy array when concatenating and it's dimension was `()` using the shape command. not sure if this means it was flattened or not but when I tried to use reshape , it didnt work and said `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (889,22)`

What I did to solve this was replace the line `one_hot = OneHotEncoder()` with `one_hot = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)` which makes the type of output matrix a dense numpy array which can be concatenated using `np.concatenate((x_num,x_cat),axis = 1 )`